# python printing out a array of bytes via serial port

Tags: python

I am kind a new to python and I am trying to print out an array of bytes which I am receiving via a serial interface.

The code Looks like this

```python
print('Teststring')
ref.ser.write('outx=0\n'.encode())
ref.ser.flush()
s = self.ser.read(size=10)
print(s)
```

I am expecting the printout to look like this

```
Teststring
INPUT DATA (Input of my bytearray s)
```

So the behaviour is like I have an external device which I want to send an reply to my write/flush command and receive the data via the serial input and print out the received information on my computer.

Right now the issue is that the computer is not printing out the expected input data.

I guess my problem is that I need to convert the data s to a string or something like that?

Comment: what does it print right now?

Comment: the print Looks like this: Teststring   outx=0

Comment: can you print the length also? it may contain a header which is not printable/contains null chars. Try this: `print(repr(s))`. If the reply contains null chars the print stops at the first null char even if there is data after that.

Comment: if i am doing it with print(repr(s)) my output Looks like this: Teststring outx=0\n

Comment: sounds that you are reading what you just written what did you expect?

Comment: i've expected the device to send something different than that, so the issue is at the external device and not at the commands right?